# An id variable for scienmetric map

Tags: r

Experimenting with this example:

```
library(bibliometrix)
data(scientometrics, package = "bibliometrixData")
years=c(2000)
nexus <- thematicEvolution(scientometrics,field="ID",years=years,n=100,minFreq=2)
```

It is possible to produce a thematic map. From where the ID column comes from? the variables in scopus there is any don't have this id. Any help from where it comes from, as I have only a downloaded dataset from scopus.

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded data contains the variable `ID` as much as possible. Note, however, that this data is shared without being loaded into memory (promised data).
For this, after `data(scientometrics, package =" bibliometrixData ")` in Environment you will see this

[image]

If you do, for example, `print(scientometrics)` it will be there.

[image]

So as you can see, `scientometrics` contains the variable `ID`.
Also `thematicEvolution` works fine.